# error : name lookup timed out

Tags: php, facebook

---

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $APP_ID,
    'secret' => $APP_My code is the same as above.SECRET,
)); //'cookie' => true,

$debug->debug("new Facebook");

$me = $facebook->getUser();
if ($me) {
    try {

        //$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
        $debug->debug("new logoutUrl", null, INFO);

        $me_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

---

My code is the same as above.

php sdk is facebook-php-sdk-v3.1.1-25-g6c82b3f.

Ever since to change the SDK update this thing,
error message is "name lookup timed out".
$facebook->api('/me') is not working!!!!!!

Resolved that there are people?

very urgent.!

Answer (score 1):

That's not a Facebook API error message - is your DNS server able to resolve graph.facebook.com correctly?

Answer (score -2):

Go to the `facebookClient.php` file and change

```
const DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 60;
```

to something higher, such as

```
const DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 696969420;
```