# Facebook php SDK v5 name lookup timed out

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i had a perfectly working php login script for my website until today , when trying to login it returns this error:

```
Facebook SDK returned an error: name lookup timed out
```

has anyone experienced the same issue? whats the solution?
My facebook sdk is v5 and graph version is 2.5

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is a server issue on your end, there is another thread without an upvoted or accepted answer: [error : name lookup timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210530/error-name-lookup-timed-out)

The existing answer is from a Facebook employee though. Contact your provider.

Comment: you should contact your provider